# what is the error in this code datagridview?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MOSTAFA;Initial Catalog=mohasba;Integrated Security=True");
SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from قيد_اليوميه where رقم_القيد='" + textBox1.Text + "'", con);
con.Open();
DataTable DT = new DataTable();
SDA.Fill(DT);
dataGridView1.DataSource = SDA;
```

When I run this code the the datagridview appear Empty

Comment: You're not actually taking user input and injecting it directly into a SQL statement, are you?

Comment: Run the query from Management Studio and see if you get results there.

Comment: Have you looked at your result set? Are there any rows being returned for the value you supply in the textbox?

Answer (score 1):

If there's no error message, and the datagrid is empty, it's very likely in your SQL.  Have you tried running it directly?  Does it return results?

If that works, doublecheck the value of textbox1.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the DataGridView has automatic column generation property set. If the datagridview is set to manual generation of column, it won't display the data. You have to map the columns to the sql column manually.

1. make sure the query returns data
2. make sure datagridview has its automatic property set. If it doesn't work delete the datagridview and put a new datagridview and don't change any information about the datagridview. Default behavior is automatic data column generation, which should display the data.

Answer (score 0):

you missed the dataGridView.dataBind();
this will Bind your data with the control

dataGridView1.DataSource = SDA;

```
dataGridView1.dataBind();
```

Comment: I have try this and get the following Error 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'DataBind' and no extension method 'DataBind' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Darsh it helps if you tell us you're using WinForms :) I added the tag to your question.

Comment: DataBind() use for WEB

Answer (score 0):

Change the DataSource to `DT`.

This:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = SDA;
```

To This:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = DT;
```